# How to know current logged in user on OpenLDAP 2.3 server?

Tags: openldap

How do I know the current logged in users on OpenLDAP 2.3 server? I have configured OpenLDAP 2.3 `slurpd` replication and my requirement is to know who are all logged in to the systems with using their LDAP account.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Users are only *bound* (not logged-in) to an LDAP server for quite short periods of time while they are establishing their own identity. Most of the time it is *applications* which are logged into the LDAP server, to search it, look up user's permissions, etc, but those connections are quite short-lived as well, although typically prolonged a bit by client-side connection pooling.

You shouldn't be using 2.3: it is many years out of date. Current version of OpenLDAP is 2.4.40, and 2.4.26 was released three years ago. I can't even find how old 2.3 is. You shouldn't be using `slurpd` replication: it's been obsolete for many years too. You should be using `syncrepl.`

Comment: Slurpd is replicating the modification update to the slave.Where as he syncrepl is not effectively replicating the changes up to date like slurpd and also when comes to the log files.while using the slurpd we have replication log to verify the changes but, in case of syncrepl loggin the changes is difficult task.

Comment: So fix your `syncrepl` configuration. I've been using it for about six years with zero problems. Why do you think you need to know who's 'logged in'?

Comment: to make a report of logged in users on a given time and also it will be easy for admin to know whether user was online during a given time slot as we can not check in each server about the logged in users.And also if you have configuration steps for syncrepl .Please share with me .

Comment: You can add the `accesslog` overlay, that logs all the recent binds and disconnects. My syncrepl configuration is straight out of the OpenLDAP documentation apart from the SSL part.

Comment: But you should still be aware that there is really no such thing as being logged into LDAP.

Comment: Hi!! it's me again . Sorry to bother you. I configured the syncrepl replication on client/server.on both server is up and running .But, on client side when i do the ldapsearch iam not getting the details like master.Do, i need to import DB files from mster or do i need to create any DN in slave.Please let me know the steps on client side.

Comment: The following is the error from slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf on slave   .line 120 (serverID      1)
/etc/openldap/slapd.conf: line 120: unknown directive <serverID> inside backend database definition (ignored).
line 121 (>syncrepl rid=001)
/etc/openldap/slapd.conf: line 121: unknown directive <>syncrepl> inside backend database definition (ignored).
line 122 (>provider=ldap://master:389)
/etc/openldap/slapd.conf: line 122: unknown directive <>pro

Comment: You should start a separate question for your syncrepl problem. This one is about logged-in users.  I don't know why you even mentioned replication in the first place, it's completely irrelevant.